# Portal for ArcGIS - Group Administrator only

Tags: arcgis-portal

Would it be possible to have Portal for ArcGIS local administrators being able to manage their group only?

Basically, admin of group A should not be able to view or edit group B. I want to assign administrator level 2 role only for the group he/she owns.  The Portal administrator will create private groups and assign admins for each groups to manage their own content and membership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, admins will always see all content. Publishers can create their own group and invite others but won't see groups they are not part of. However they won't have administrative rights.